# what to put in header for navbar__list__item_content navbar__list__item_content--checked

Tags: html, class, navbar

hello can you guys help me out with a website I'm working on
I want to use this code but it seems to show me a square :

```
<div class="navbar__list__item_content navbar__list__item_content--checked"></div>
```

I hade earlier a problem with :
font-awesome.min
but I fixed it through putting this link in the head :

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

could you guys help me I'm new at this 
Thanks :D

Comment: What is the CSS related to those classes?

Comment: http://checker.yelam.ml/styles.bundle.min.css

Comment: this one is related to : <div class="navbar__list__item_content navbar__list__item_content--checked"></div>

Comment: @RickCalder please help what should I do ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry please add the class, not minified, to the question.

Comment: what do you mean ?